# Exclude category children get_categories

Tags: wordpress

I'm not sure why this isn't working.  I want to exclude categories 406, 982, and 1319 and their children from the list. I don't see any other arguments on wp codex. Does 'exclude' automatically exclude children? Is there another way to do this?

**Edit: I can't even limit the results to 10.

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'exclude' => '406,982,1319',
    '#'       => '10'
);
$sidebar_artists = get_categories($args);

echo "<ul>";
foreach ($sidebar_artists as $sidebar_artist) {

    echo '<li class="cat-item">' . $sidebar_artist->category_nicename . '</li>';
}
echo "</ul>";
?>
```

Comment: Can you describe in more detail how it's not working?

Comment: It's showing them all. All categories and children. I want to show category 406, 982 and 1319 separately. And then show the rest of the categories, except the above mentioned in the sidebar.

Comment: It looks like it should be working; have you double-checked that the category ids are correct?

Comment: What happens if you try `wp_list_categories` with the same arguments?  (No reason this should work if the above doesn't, just trying to see if the problem can be isolated).

Comment: same thing. won't exclude. and I see that I can't control the number of categories returned. That wouldn't be a problem but why won't it exclude?

Comment: What happens if you try `foreach (get_categories('exclude=406,982,1319') as $sidebar_artist) {` (again, this is just trying to isolate the problem, since your code looks fine).

Answer (score 3):

Set parent to 0:

```
<?php
$args = array(
  'orderby' => 'name',
  'parent' => 0
  );
$categories = get_categories( $args );
foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
    echo '<a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '">' . $category->name . '</a><br/>';
}
?>
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories

Answer (score 0):

it looks like it should be working but did you try any alternative ? like `is_category` in `if/else`? or try exclusion by category `slug`instead of IDs for sake of debugging....

[WP Codex Reference for is_category](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_category)

Comment: What do you mean by is_category? I m just trying to list categories. That s all. And it's very annoying because I m following wordpress codex ... and it s still not working.